# Call Javascript function from C# static web method (page method)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, static, webmethod

I used:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "", "MyJSFunction('parameter')", true);
```

to reach the `MyJSFunction` function in JavaScript from `Page_Load` and it worked fine. Now I'm in need of calling lets say the same function but from a static web method, but I get these 2 errors on `this` & `GetType()`:

> this: Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method,
>   or a static field initialized.
>
> GetType(): An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property, 'objec.GetType()'.

I tried to re-format the code like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((Page)(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler), ((Page)(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler)).GetType(), "", "MyJSFunction('parameter')", true);
```

No errors shown, but it doesn't reach the JavaScript function.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the JavaScript function upon successful completion (callback) of the call to the web method *in your JS code*. You can't "call" client-side code from the code behind; you can register a JS function call as a "startup script" but not here as a call to a web method does not involve a postback of the page nor does it cause Page_Load to run.